# NameError: Global Name 'test' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, module

Hi I have two python files: project.py and test.py.

I am trying to import variable from test.py to project.py.

Following is the code:

test.py

```
newton = 0
def apple(n):
    global newton
    n = newton
    time.sleep(15)
    n = n + 1
    return
```

and in project.py

```
from test import *
class search(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.servo = test.apple(n)
      def run(self):
          while (self.servo < 1):
                print "hELLO"
```

When I run project.py I get NameError: Global name 'test' is not defined in project.py self.servo = test.apple(n)

Can anyone point out what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting `test` to be?

```py
from test import *
```

This will load everything found in test, which in this case is test.py. So that will load the following into the global namespace:

- `newton` (with a value of `0`)
- `apple` (a function)

It does not load any symbol named `test`, so when you call `test.apple` in your `__init__` method, you get a `NameError`.

If you want to import test.py as `test`, you instead need to just import the module itself, not import things *from* the module:

```
import test
```

Comment: @ Dan Lowe I removed the test in test.apple(n) but i still get a NameError but this time with 'n'. In fact i am not too sure how can i make self.servo take up the value of n

Comment: @Sevyon Until you _use_ `n` on line 4 of project.py, it's never mentioned. It doesn't exist. I think you may need to do some more reading about variable scope and how to construct classes in Python.